# How many natural numbers $\leq 100$ are not of the form $n^2,n^3,n^5?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given a set $S$ of natural numbers lesser or equal to $100$ that are NOT of the form $n^2$, $n^3$, $n^5$, what is the cardinality of $S$?

Naturally, I just computed how many numbers are of that form and subtracted it, which gave me $84$. I was given the hint that $2^7=128>100$ but I'm not sure what to do with this information.

Comment: It's probably intended for you to use inclusion/exclusion.

Comment: if you are unsure, try setting $n=32$, and using inclusion/exclusion.  Then, with $n=32$, consider each number individually and see if you get the same computation.

Comment: How did you get $44$?  There are only $10$ squares, $4$ cubes, and $2$ fifth powers up to $100$, and some of those are the same, so there should be much more than $44$ numbers not of those forms

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Yeah I meant to type 84 but somehow thought of $128-84=44$ for some reason

Comment: The only possible relevance of $2^7>100$ that I see is that by excluding powers with prime exponents $2$, $3$, and $5$, you've actually excluded all powers with exponent (prime or composite) greater than $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume $0$ is not a natural number.

Since $100=10^2$, there are $\color{blue}{10}$ squares up to $100$.

Since $\lfloor\sqrt[3]{100}\rfloor=4$, there are $\color{blue}4$ cubes up to $100$.

Since $2^5<100$ but $3^5>100$, there are $\color{blue}2$ fifth powers up to $100$.

There are $\color{orange}2$ sixth powers up to $100$, and $1$ is in all $\color{lime}3$ of the above sets.

So I get $\color{blue}{10}+\color{blue}4+\color{blue}2-\color{orange}1-\color{lime}2=13$ squares/cubes/fifth powers up to $100$,

which means $87$ numbers up to $100$ that are not those.

Comment: I've used the inclusion/exclusion principle as mentioned by @Angina Seng and got 86 (sixth powers weren't asked) but your method is faster, thanks!

Comment: I think the answer is $87$.  Sixth powers are squares and cubes, and $1$ is a square, cube, and fifth power

Comment: Yes you are right, I counted $64=8^2=4^3$ twice