# Find the number of natural numbers less than or equal to 10^8 which are neither perfect squares, nor perfect cubes, nor perfect fifth powers.

Tags: combinatorics

No. of perfect squares= 1^2,2^2,3^2,.......,10^4^2=10^4 numbers
No. of perfect cubes= 1^3,2^3,3^3,........,464^3=464 numbers
No.of perfect fifth powers=1^5,2^5,3^5,.......,39^5=39 numbers
Therefore,
10^8-10^4-464-39=99989497
But there are 29 repetitions, adding them to the result will give the final answers.
Therefore, 99989497+29=99989526

I tried using calculator to solve this, but couldn't find a way without it.

Comment: First hint : Determine the number of perfect squares, cubes and fifth powers upto $10^8$ Second hint : For this, use inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Don't count the perfect powers more than once.

Comment: The number of positive $n$th powers less than or equal to some natural number $K$ is $\sqrt[n]{K}$, rounded down. No need to actually calculate all the powers and count them. It can be a bit tricky to use this to find that there are $39$ fifth powers, for instance, but with a minute or two to calculate and a little persistence it is definitely doable.

Comment: (Equivalently, show that $39^5$ is small enough and $40^5$ is too large. Without calculating any other fifth powers, this will tell you that there are $39$ fifth powers. And how could you guess this without first calculating a lot of fifth powers? By knowing that $\sqrt[5]{10^8}=10\sqrt[5]{1000}$, and $\sqrt[5]{1024}=4$. So $40$ is _just barely_ too large.)

Comment: [Similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3844827/how-many-natural-numbers-leq-100-are-not-of-the-form-n2-n3-n5/3844887#3844887)

Answer (score 1):

The number of perfect squares will be $k_2$, with $k_2^2 \leq 10^8 \Leftrightarrow k_2 \leq 10^4$. So, as you said, there are $10^4$ perfect squares in this range.

The number f perfect cubes will be $k_3$, with $k_3^3 \leq 10^8 \Leftrightarrow k_3 \leq 464$ (here I did use the calculator to help with computing $10^{8/3}$.

The number f perfect with powers will be $k_5$, with $k_5^5 \leq 10^8 \Leftrightarrow k_5 \leq 39$ (here I did use the calculator to help with computing $10^{8/5}$.

Now, excluding the duplicates... the cubes that are also squares are the sixth powers, which are 21. The fifth powers that are also squares are the 10th powers, which are 6, and the fifth powers that are also cubes are the 15th powers, which are 2 (leaving out $1^5$ that already discounted).

Adding up: $10^4+464+39-21-6-2 = 10474$, which corresponds to your result.